# Returning mutated inputs with Dask

Tags: python, dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed

I have a data flow that mutates then returns the input with Dask:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
import numpy as np
from typing import List

def update(model: np.ndarray, change: List[float]) -> np.ndarray:
    change = np.asarray(change)
    model -= change.mean()
    return model

def use(model: np.ndarray, val: float) -> float:
    assert np.allclose(model.mean(), val)
    return 1.0

client = Client()
model = np.zeros(10)
model_future = client.scatter(model)

for i in range(10):
    val_future = [client.submit(use, model_future, -i) for _ in range(4)]
    model_future = client.submit(update, model_future, val_future)

print(model_future.result())  # [-10., ...]
```

Clearly, this works and produces the expected result. However, this example is explicitly warned against in Dask's [Best Practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-mutate-inputs), and mutating the input is warned against in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650190/how-does-dask-delayed-handle-mutable-inputs/48652952#48652952).

In my use case, copying the input with `deepcopy` is an expensive operation – including `model = deepcopy(model)` would double the time of an `update` call. I'm inclined to avoid running `deepcopy` on each worker, especially because the example above works.

My question: does the data flow above resolve the issues Dask has with mutating inputs? The mutated input is returned, which I presume helps. When would the example above not produce the expected result?

Comment: The reason that dask discourages mutating input is because is you can create a race condition. In the example you wrote here, you can imagine that you submit your `use` and `update` and they start running asynchronously. It could happen that one of your `update` calls runs before all your `use` calls are finished and then your next call to `use` is now operating on one of your `model` objects that has had its values changed out from underneath via `update` function being called out of expected order.

Comment: Got it. Race conditions and asynchrony explain why input mutation is so strongly discouraged. This data flow is serial (the outputs of `update`/`use` are inputs to `use`/`serial` respectively), so that's not a concern here.